# Best value of $X$ dice thrown: expected value

Tags: probability, dice, expected-value

***It has been a long time I didn't practice probabilities. If I made notation mistakes, please let me know, thus I can fix it.***

---

## History

I play a game where I use **ten-sided dice**. Depending on my bonus, I have the possibility to **throw two dices and keep the highest value** from these two dices. The bonus allows me to throw **up to 10 dice**, and keep the highest value. I want to know the **expected value depending of the number of dice thrown**.

---

## What I tried

I tried to guess probability based on lower number of dices, recursively. Thus, I got this equation:

$$P_{d}(R) = P_{1}(R)\cdot P_{d-1}(\le R) + P_{1}(\lt R)\cdot P_{d-1}(R)$$

### Notation

$d$ : number of thrown dice 
$R$ : result (highest value from all dice)
$P_{d}(R)$ : probability to get result $R$ with $d$ dice throws
$P_{1}(\le R) ; P_{1}(\lt R)$ : probability to get result **lower-or-equal** or **lower-than** $R$

### Known values

$P_{1}(R) = \frac{1}{10}$
$P_{d}(\le R) = \Bigl(\frac{R}{10}\Bigr)^{d}$
$P_{d}(\lt R) = P_{d}(\le R-1) = \Bigl(\frac{R-1}{10}\Bigr)^{d}$

### Explanation

There are two ways to get a result $R$ :

- the first die equals $R$ and the others are lower-or-equal to $R$
  $$P_{1}(R)\cdot P_{d-1}(\le R)$$
- the first die is lower than $R$ and the best of other dice is equals to $R$
  $$P_{1}(\lt R)\cdot P_{d-1}(R)$$

As these two possibilities are disjointed (no possibility in common), we can sum the two equations to get the final equation.

### Results

I implemented these equations using *Excel*, here are my results:

[image: Equations results]

*The vertical axis represent the number $d$ of thrown dice. The horizontal axis represent the result $R$. The **Esp** column stands for the **expected value** (named Esperance in french).*

---

## Question

**Might you please check that my reasoning is correct? If yes, do my results seem correct too? If not, what is wrong?**

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Dealing_with_discrete_variables. The formula simplifies quite a bit for the max or min value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column with expected values provide the correct values. However, I would suggest simplifying your argument in the following way.

\begin{equation}
      P_d(R) = P_d(\leq R)-P_d(\leq R-1) = \Bigl(\frac{R}{10}\Bigr)^{d} - \Bigl(\frac{R-1}{10}\Bigr)^{d}
\end{equation}

This simplifies calculating the expected value.
\begin{equation}
      \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[R] = \sum_{R=1}^{10} R * P_d(R) = 
      \sum_{R=1}^{10} R * (P_d(\leq R)-P_d(\leq R-1))
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
      = \sum_{R=1}^{10} R * P_d(\leq R)-(R-1)*P_d(\leq R-1)) - 
      P_d(\leq R-1))
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
      = 10 * P_d(\leq 10) - \sum_{R=1}^{9} P_d(\leq R) = 10 - 
      \sum_{R=1}^{9} \Bigl(\frac{R}{10}\Bigr)^{d}
\end{equation}